# How to get Selected Values Ids using Jquery ComboTreePlugin.js Plugin?

Tags: jquery

How to get Selected Values Ids using Jquery ComboTreePlugin.js Plugin?

I am Using ComboTreePlugin.js Jquery plugin for multiselect component.Following is code snippet..."resultData" is dynamically populated as shown from a ajax get. When the form is submitted i get the selected values as array of String.... for e.g if i have selected "Masters,Course,Subject,Registration" , in form submit i get ["Masters","Course","Subject","Registration"] String array for
 $('#MenuTree').val()....

```
            function myTree(){
             var resultData = [{id=12, title=Masters, 
                subs=[{id=15, title=Course},
                     {id=16, title=Subject}]},
             {id=13, title=Registration,
                subs=[{id=18, title=Student}, 
                     {id=19, title=Faculty}]},
             {id=14, title=Admin, 
                subs=[{id=17, title=User}]}, 
             {id=20, title=DashBoard, subs=[]},
             {id=22, title=LogOut, subs=[]}];


             $('#MenuTree').comboTree({
                source : resultData,
                isMultiple: true
              });
             }
```

But i need to access the ids of selected values as [12,15,16,13]....how can i get it?

Comment: Have you tried var selectedIds = comboTree1.getSelectedItemsId(); Read the documentation https://github.com/kirlisakal/combo-tree before post on internet.

Answer (score 0):

To get ids please follow the instruction

first go to jquery file comboTreePlugin.js: line no 390 approx

and replace the code with

```
 ComboTree.prototype.refreshInputVal = function() {
    var tmpTitle = "",
        tempids = "";

    if (this.options.isMultiple) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this._selectedItems.length; i++) {
            tmpTitle += this._selectedItems[i].title;
            tempids += this._selectedItems[i].id
            if (i < this._selectedItems.length - 1) {
                tmpTitle += ", ";
                tempids += ", ";
            }
        }
    } else {
        tmpTitle = this._selectedItem.title;
        tempids = this._selectedItem.ids;
    }

    console.log(tempids); //Singh
    this._elemInput.val(tmpTitle);
    this._elemInput.trigger('change');

    if (this.changeHandler)
        this.changeHandler();
};
```

With previous code that is :

```
 ComboTree.prototype.refreshInputVal = function () {
    var tmpTitle = "";

    if (this.options.isMultiple) {
        for (var i=0; i<this._selectedItems.length; i++){
            tmpTitle += this._selectedItems[i].title;
            if (i<this._selectedItems.length-1)
                tmpTitle += ", ";
        }
    }
    else {
        tmpTitle = this._selectedItem.title;
    }

    this._elemInput.val(tmpTitle);
    this._elemInput.trigger('change');

    if (this.changeHandler)
        this.changeHandler();
};
```

note:
 To get ids you have to give your input name. I outputting values using console.log function please review upper code

( console.log(tempids); //Singh  )  here you get ids in cosole

Answer (score 0):

```js
/*!
 * jQuery ComboTree Plugin 
 * Author:  Erhan FIRAT
 * Mail:    erhanfirat@gmail.com
 * Licensed under the MIT license
 * Version: 1.2.1
 */


;
(function($, window, document, undefined) {

    // Default settings
    var comboTreePlugin = 'comboTree',
        defaults = {
            source: [],
            isMultiple: false,
            cascadeSelect: false,
            selected: [],
            collapse: false,
            hiddeninput: false,

        };

    // LIFE CYCLE
    function ComboTree(element, options) {

        this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = comboTreePlugin;

        this.constructorFunc(element, options);
    }

    ComboTree.prototype.constructorFunc = function(element, options) {
        this.elemInput = element;
        this._elemInput = $(element);

        this.init();
    }

    ComboTree.prototype.init = function() {
        // Setting Doms
        this.comboTreeId = 'comboTree' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999);

        this._elemInput.addClass('comboTreeInputBox');

        if (this._elemInput.attr('id') === undefined)
            this._elemInput.attr('id', this.comboTreeId + 'Input');
        this.elemInputId = this._elemInput.attr('id');

        this._elemInput.wrap('<div id="' + this.comboTreeId + 'Wrapper" class="comboTreeWrapper"></div>');
        this._elemInput.wrap('<div id="' + this.comboTreeId + 'InputWrapper" class="comboTreeInputWrapper"></div>');
        this._elemWrapper = $('#' + this.comboTreeId + 'Wrapper');

        this._elemArrowBtn = $('<div id="' + this.comboTreeId + 'ArrowBtn" class="comboTreeArrowBtn" type="button"><span class="mdi mdi-chevron-down comboTreeArrowBtnImg"></span></div>');
        this._elemInput.after(this._elemArrowBtn);
        this._elemWrapper.append('<div id="' + this.comboTreeId + 'DropDownContainer" class="comboTreeDropDownContainer"><div class="comboTreeDropDownContent"></div>');

        // DORP DOWN AREA
        this._elemDropDownContainer = $('#' + this.comboTreeId + 'DropDownContainer');

        this._elemDropDownContainer.html(this.createSourceHTML());
        this._elemFilterInput = this.options.isMultiple ? $('#' + this.comboTreeId + 'MultiFilter') : null;
        this._elemSourceUl = $('#' + this.comboTreeId + 'ComboTreeSourceUl');

        this._elemItems = this._elemDropDownContainer.find('li');
        this._elemItemsTitle = this._elemDropDownContainer.find('span.comboTreeItemTitle');

        // VARIABLES
        this._selectedItem = {};
        this._selectedItems = [];

        this.processSelected();

        this.bindings();
    };

    ComboTree.prototype.unbind = function() {
        this._elemArrowBtn.off('click');
        this._elemInput.off('click');
        this._elemItems.off('click');
        this._elemItemsTitle.off('click');
        this._elemItemsTitle.off("mousemove");
        this._elemInput.off('keyup');
        this._elemInput.off('keydown');
        this._elemInput.off('mouseup.' + this.comboTreeId);
        $(document).off('mouseup.' + this.comboTreeId);
    }

    ComboTree.prototype.destroy = function() {
        this.unbind();
        this._elemWrapper.before(this._elemInput);
        this._elemWrapper.remove();
        //this._elemInput.removeData('plugin_' + comboTreePlugin);
    }



    // CREATE DOM HTMLs

    ComboTree.prototype.removeSourceHTML = function() {
        this._elemDropDownContainer.html('');
    };

    ComboTree.prototype.createSourceHTML = function() {
        var sourceHTML = '';
        if (this.options.isMultiple)
            sourceHTML = this.createFilterHTMLForMultiSelect();
        sourceHTML += this.createSourceSubItemsHTML(this.options.source);
        return sourceHTML;
    };

    ComboTree.prototype.createFilterHTMLForMultiSelect = function() {
        return '<input id="' + this.comboTreeId + 'MultiFilter" type="text" class="multiplesFilter" placeholder="Type to filter"/>';
    }

    ComboTree.prototype.createSourceSubItemsHTML = function(subItems, parentId) {
        var subItemsHtml = '<UL id="' + this.comboTreeId + 'ComboTreeSourceUl' + (parentId ? parentId : 'main') + '" style="' + ((this.options.collapse && parentId) ? 'display:none;' : '') + '">';
        for (var i = 0; i < subItems.length; i++) {
            subItemsHtml += this.createSourceItemHTML(subItems[i]);
        }
        subItemsHtml += '</UL>'
        return subItemsHtml;
    }

    ComboTree.prototype.createSourceItemHTML = function(sourceItem) {
        var itemHtml = "",
            isThereSubs = sourceItem.hasOwnProperty("subs");
        let isSelectable = (sourceItem.isSelectable === undefined ? true : sourceItem.isSelectable);


        itemHtml = '<LI id="' + this.comboTreeId + 'Li' + sourceItem.id + '" class="ComboTreeItem' + (isThereSubs ? 'Parent' : 'Chlid') + '"> ';

        if (isThereSubs)
            itemHtml += '<span class="comboTreeParentPlus">' + (this.options.collapse ? '<span class="mdi mdi-chevron-right-circle-outline"></span>' : '<span class="mdi mdi-chevron-down-circle-outline"></span>') + '</span>'; // itemHtml += '<span class="comboTreeParentPlus">' + (this.options.collapse ? '+' : '&minus;') + '</span>';

        if (this.options.isMultiple)
            itemHtml += '<span data-id="' + sourceItem.id + '" data-selectable="' + isSelectable + '" class="comboTreeItemTitle ' + (isSelectable ? 'selectable' : 'not-selectable') + '">' + (isSelectable ? '<input type="checkbox" />' : '') + sourceItem.title + '</span>';
        else
            itemHtml += '<span data-id="' + sourceItem.id + '" data-selectable="' + isSelectable + '" class="comboTreeItemTitle ' + (isSelectable ? 'selectable' : 'not-selectable') + '">' + sourceItem.title + '</span>';

        if (isThereSubs)
            itemHtml += this.createSourceSubItemsHTML(sourceItem.subs, sourceItem.id);

        itemHtml += '</LI>';
        return itemHtml;
    };


    // BINDINGS

    ComboTree.prototype.bindings = function() {
        var _this = this;

        $(this._elemInput).focus(function(e) {
            if (!_this._elemDropDownContainer.is(':visible'))
                $(_this._elemDropDownContainer).slideToggle(100);
        });

        this._elemArrowBtn.on('click', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            _this.toggleDropDown();
        });
        this._elemInput.on('click', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            if (!_this._elemDropDownContainer.is(':visible'))
                _this.toggleDropDown();
        });
        this._elemItems.on('click', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            if ($(this).hasClass('ComboTreeItemParent')) {
                _this.toggleSelectionTree(this);
            }
        });
        this._elemItemsTitle.on('click', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            if (_this.options.isMultiple)
                _this.multiItemClick(this);
            else
                _this.singleItemClick(this);
        });
        this._elemItemsTitle.on("mousemove", function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            _this.dropDownMenuHover(this);
        });

        // KEY BINDINGS
        this._elemInput.on('keyup', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();

            switch (e.keyCode) {
                case 27:
                    _this.closeDropDownMenu();
                    break;
                case 13:
                case 39:
                case 37:
                case 40:
                case 38:
                    e.preventDefault();
                    break;
                default:
                    if (!_this.options.isMultiple)
                        _this.filterDropDownMenu();
                    break;
            }
        });

        this._elemFilterInput && this._elemFilterInput.on('keyup', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();

            switch (e.keyCode) {
                case 27:
                    if ($(this).val()) {
                        $(this).val('');
                        _this.filterDropDownMenu();
                    } else {
                        _this.closeDropDownMenu();
                    }
                    break;
                case 40:
                case 38:
                    e.preventDefault();
                    _this.dropDownInputKeyControl(e.keyCode - 39);
                    break;
                case 37:
                case 39:
                    e.preventDefault();
                    _this.dropDownInputKeyToggleTreeControl(e.keyCode - 38);
                    break;
                case 13:
                    _this.multiItemClick(_this._elemHoveredItem);
                    e.preventDefault();
                    break;
                default:
                    _this.filterDropDownMenu();
                    break;
            }
        });

        this._elemInput.on('keydown', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();

            switch (e.keyCode) {
                case 9:
                    _this.closeDropDownMenu();
                    break;
                case 40:
                case 38:
                    e.preventDefault();
                    _this.dropDownInputKeyControl(e.keyCode - 39);
                    break;
                case 37:
                case 39:
                    e.preventDefault();
                    _this.dropDownInputKeyToggleTreeControl(e.keyCode - 38);
                    break;
                case 13:
                    if (_this.options.isMultiple)
                        _this.multiItemClick(_this._elemHoveredItem);
                    else
                        _this.singleItemClick(_this._elemHoveredItem);
                    e.preventDefault();
                    break;
                default:
                    if (_this.options.isMultiple)
                        e.preventDefault();
            }
        });


        // ON FOCUS OUT CLOSE DROPDOWN
        $(document).on('mouseup.' + _this.comboTreeId, function(e) {
            if (!_this._elemWrapper.is(e.target) && _this._elemWrapper.has(e.target).length === 0 && _this._elemDropDownContainer.is(':visible'))
                _this.closeDropDownMenu();
        });
    };





    // EVENTS HERE

    // DropDown Menu Open/Close
    ComboTree.prototype.toggleDropDown = function() {
        let _this = this;
        $(this._elemDropDownContainer).slideToggle(100, function() {
            if (_this._elemDropDownContainer.is(':visible'))
                $(_this._elemInput).focus();
        });
    };

    ComboTree.prototype.closeDropDownMenu = function() {
        $(this._elemDropDownContainer).slideUp(100);
    };

    // Selection Tree Open/Close
    ComboTree.prototype.toggleSelectionTree = function(item, direction) {
        var subMenu = $(item).children('ul')[0];
        if (direction === undefined) {
            if ($(subMenu).is(':visible'))
                $(item).children('span.comboTreeParentPlus').html('<span class="mdi mdi-chevron-right-circle-outline"></span>'); //$(item).children('span.comboTreeParentPlus').html("+");
            else
                $(item).children('span.comboTreeParentPlus').html('<span class="mdi mdi-chevron-down-circle-outline"></span>'); //$(item).children('span.comboTreeParentPlus').html("&minus;");

            $(subMenu).slideToggle(50);
        } else if (direction == 1 && !$(subMenu).is(':visible')) {
            $(item).children('span.comboTreeParentPlus').html('<span class="mdi mdi-chevron-down-circle-outline"></span>'); //$(item).children('span.comboTreeParentPlus').html("&minus;");
            $(subMenu).slideDown(50);
        } else if (direction == -1) {
            if ($(subMenu).is(':visible')) {
                $(item).children('span.comboTreeParentPlus').html('<span class="mdi mdi-chevron-right-circle-outline"></span>'); //$(item).children('span.comboTreeParentPlus').html("+");
                $(subMenu).slideUp(50);
            } else {
                this.dropDownMenuHoverToParentItem(item);
            }
        }

    };


    // SELECTION FUNCTIONS
    ComboTree.prototype.selectMultipleItem = function(ctItem) {
        if ($(ctItem).data("selectable") == true) {
            this._selectedItem = {
                id: $(ctItem).attr("data-id"),
                title: $(ctItem).text()
            };

            let check = this.isItemInArray(this._selectedItem, this.options.source);
            if (check) {
                var index = this.isItemInArray(this._selectedItem, this._selectedItems);
                if (index) {
                    this._selectedItems.splice(parseInt(index), 1);
                    $(ctItem).find("input").prop('checked', false);
                } else {
                    this._selectedItems.push(this._selectedItem);
                    $(ctItem).find("input").prop('checked', true);
                }
            } // if check
        } // if selectable
    };

    ComboTree.prototype.singleItemClick = function(ctItem) {
        if ($(ctItem).data("selectable") == true) {
            this._selectedItem = {
                id: $(ctItem).attr("data-id"),
                title: $(ctItem).text()
            };
        } // if selectable

        this.refreshInputVal();
        this.closeDropDownMenu();
    };

    ComboTree.prototype.multiItemClick = function(ctItem) {
        this.selectMultipleItem(ctItem);

        if (this.options.cascadeSelect) {
            if ($(ctItem).parent('li').hasClass('ComboTreeItemParent')) {
                var subMenu = $(ctItem).parent('li').children('ul').first().find('input[type="checkbox"]');
                subMenu.each(function() {
                    var $input = $(this)
                    if ($(ctItem).children('input[type="checkbox"]').first().prop("checked") !== $input.prop('checked')) {
                        $input.prop('checked', !$(ctItem).children('input[type="checkbox"]').first().prop("checked"));
                        $input.trigger('click');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        this.refreshInputVal();
    };


    // recursive search for item in arr
    ComboTree.prototype.isItemInArray = function(item, arr) {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (item.id == arr[i].id && item.title == arr[i].title)
                return i + "";

            if (arr[i].hasOwnProperty("subs")) {
                let found = this.isItemInArray(item, arr[i].subs);
                if (found)
                    return found;
            }
        }
        return false;
    };

    ComboTree.prototype.refreshInputVal = function() {
        var tmpTitle = "",
            tempids = "";

        if (this.options.isMultiple) {
            for (var i = 0; i < this._selectedItems.length; i++) {
                tmpTitle += this._selectedItems[i].title;
                tempids += this._selectedItems[i].id
                if (i < this._selectedItems.length - 1) {
                    tmpTitle += ", ";
                    tempids += ", ";
                }
            }
        } else {
            tmpTitle = this._selectedItem.title;
            tempids = this._selectedItem.ids;
        }

        if (this.options.hiddeninput) {
            console.log(tempids); //lucky
            $(this.options.hiddeninput).val(tempids)

        }

        this._elemInput.val(tmpTitle);
        this._elemInput.trigger('change');

        if (this.changeHandler)
            this.changeHandler();
    };

    ComboTree.prototype.dropDownMenuHover = function(itemSpan, withScroll) {
        this._elemItems.find('span.comboTreeItemHover').removeClass('comboTreeItemHover');
        $(itemSpan).addClass('comboTreeItemHover');
        this._elemHoveredItem = $(itemSpan);
        if (withScroll)
            this.dropDownScrollToHoveredItem(this._elemHoveredItem);
    }

    ComboTree.prototype.dropDownScrollToHoveredItem = function(itemSpan) {
        var curScroll = this._elemSourceUl.scrollTop();
        this._elemSourceUl.scrollTop(curScroll + $(itemSpan).parent().position().top - 80);
    }

    ComboTree.prototype.dropDownMenuHoverToParentItem = function(item) {
        var parentSpanItem = $($(item).parents('li.ComboTreeItemParent')[0]).children("span.comboTreeItemTitle");
        if (parentSpanItem.length)
            this.dropDownMenuHover(parentSpanItem, true);
        else
            this.dropDownMenuHover(this._elemItemsTitle[0], true);
    }

    ComboTree.prototype.dropDownInputKeyToggleTreeControl = function(direction) {
        var item = this._elemHoveredItem;
        if ($(item).parent('li').hasClass('ComboTreeItemParent'))
            this.toggleSelectionTree($(item).parent('li'), direction);
        else if (direction == -1)
            this.dropDownMenuHoverToParentItem(item);
    }

    ComboTree.prototype.dropDownInputKeyControl = function(step) {
            if (!this._elemDropDownContainer.is(":visible"))
                this.toggleDropDown();

            var list = this._elemItems.find("span.comboTreeItemTitle:visible");
            i = this._elemHoveredItem ? list.index(this._elemHoveredItem) + step : 0;
            i = (list.length + i) % list.length;

            this.dropDownMenuHover(list[i], true);
        },

        ComboTree.prototype.filterDropDownMenu = function() {
            var searchText = '';
            if (!this.options.isMultiple)
                searchText = this._elemInput.val();
            else
                searchText = $("#" + this.comboTreeId + "MultiFilter").val();

            if (searchText != "") {
                this._elemItemsTitle.hide();
                this._elemItemsTitle.siblings("span.comboTreeParentPlus").hide();
                list = this._elemItems
                    .filter((index, item) => {
                        return item.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) != -1;
                    })
                    .each(function(i, elem) {
                        $(this.children).show()
                        $(this).siblings("span.comboTreeParentPlus").show();
                    });
            } else {
                this._elemItemsTitle.show();
                this._elemItemsTitle.siblings("span.comboTreeParentPlus").show();
            }
        }

    ComboTree.prototype.processSelected = function() {
        let elements = this._elemItemsTitle;
        let selectedItem = this._selectedItem;
        let selectedItems = this._selectedItems;
        this.options.selected.forEach(function(element) {
            let selected = $(elements).filter(function() {
                return $(this).data('id') == element;
            });

            if (selected.length > 0) {
                $(selected).find('input').attr('checked', true);

                selectedItem = {
                    id: selected.data("id"),
                    title: selected.text()
                };
                selectedItems.push(selectedItem);
            }
        });

        //Without this it doesn't work
        this._selectedItem = selectedItem;

        this.refreshInputVal();
    };


    // METHODS


    ComboTree.prototype.findItembyId = function(itemId, source) {
        if (itemId && source) {
            for (let i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
                if (source[i].id == itemId)
                    return { id: source[i].id, title: source[i].title };
                if (source[i].hasOwnProperty("subs")) {
                    let found = this.findItembyId(itemId, source[i].subs);
                    if (found)
                        return found;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Returns selected id array or null
    ComboTree.prototype.getSelectedIds = function() {
        if (this.options.isMultiple && this._selectedItems.length > 0) {
            var tmpArr = [];
            for (i = 0; i < this._selectedItems.length; i++)
                tmpArr.push(this._selectedItems[i].id);

            return tmpArr;
        } else if (!this.options.isMultiple && this._selectedItem.hasOwnProperty('id')) {
            return [this._selectedItem.id];
        }
        return null;
    };

    // Retuns Array (multiple), Integer (single), or False (No choice)
    ComboTree.prototype.getSelectedNames = function() {
        if (this.options.isMultiple && this._selectedItems.length > 0) {
            var tmpArr = [];
            for (i = 0; i < this._selectedItems.length; i++)
                tmpArr.push(this._selectedItems[i].title);

            return tmpArr;
        } else if (!this.options.isMultiple && this._selectedItem.hasOwnProperty('id')) {
            return this._selectedItem.title;
        }
        return null;
    };

    ComboTree.prototype.setSource = function(source) {
        this._selectedItems = [];

        this.destroy();
        this.options.source = source;
        this.constructorFunc(this.elemInput, this.options);
    };

    ComboTree.prototype.clearSelection = function() {
        for (i = 0; i < this._selectedItems.length; i++) {
            let itemElem = $("#" + this.comboTreeId + 'Li' + this._selectedItems[i].id);
            $(itemElem).find("input").prop('checked', false);
        }
        this._selectedItems = [];
        this.refreshInputVal();
    };

    ComboTree.prototype.setSelection = function(selectionIdList) {
        if (selectionIdList && selectionIdList.length && selectionIdList.length > 0) {
            for (let i = 0; i < selectionIdList.length; i++) {
                let selectedItem = this.findItembyId(selectionIdList[i], this.options.source);

                if (selectedItem) {
                    let check = this.isItemInArray(selectedItem, this.options.source);
                    if (check) {
                        var index = this.isItemInArray(selectedItem, this._selectedItems);
                        if (!index) {
                            let selectedItemElem = $("#" + this.comboTreeId + 'Li' + selectionIdList[i]);

                            this._selectedItems.push(selectedItem);
                            this._selectedItem = selectedItem;
                            $(selectedItemElem).find("input").prop('checked', true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        this.refreshInputVal();
    };


    // EVENTS

    ComboTree.prototype.onChange = function(callBack) {
        if (callBack && typeof callBack === "function")
            this.changeHandler = callBack;
    };



    // -----

    $.fn[comboTreePlugin] = function(options) {
        var ctArr = [];
        this.each(function() {
            if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + comboTreePlugin)) {
                $.data(this, 'plugin_' + comboTreePlugin, new ComboTree(this, options));
                ctArr.push($(this).data()['plugin_' + comboTreePlugin]);
            }
        });

        if (this.length == 1)
            return ctArr[0];
        else
            return ctArr;
    }

})(jQuery, window, document);

//json data 

var response = [
    {
        id: 0,
        title: 'Horse'
    }, {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Birds',
        subs: [
            {
                id: 10,
                title: 'Piegon'
            }, {
                id: 11,
                title: 'Parrot'
            }, {
                id: 12,
                title: 'Owl'
            }, {
                id: 13,
                title: 'Falcon'
            }
        ]
    }, {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Rabbit'
    }, {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Fox'
    }, {
        id: 5,
        title: 'Cats',
        subs: [
            {
                id: 50,
                title: 'Kitty'
            }, {
                id: 51,
                title: 'Bigs',
                subs: [
                    {
                        id: 510,
                        title: 'Cheetah'
                    }, {
                        id: 511,
                        title: 'Jaguar'
                    }, {
                        id: 512,
                        title: 'Leopard'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }, {
        id: 6,
        title: 'Fish'
    }
];

//json data ends here

comboTree1  = $('#cat').comboTree({
        source : response,
        isMultiple: true,
        hiddeninput:'.getids' // this is the feilds just give feilds name to get ids
        });




<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/erhanfirat/combo-tree/master/style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="cat" placeholder="choose">

<input type="text" class='.getids' >
```

in  plugin js code infront of hiddeninput please give any selector where you want your output

Answer (score 0):

We can get Ids on change of checkbox selection with following syntax. There is method available getSelectedIds in this comboTreePlugin.

```
comboTree3 = $('#input_box_id').comboTree({
    source : constCenterData,
    isMultiple: true,
    cascadeSelect: true,
    collapse: false
});

comboTree3.onChange(function(){
   console.log(comboTree3.getSelectedIds());
   $('#other_input_box_hidden').val(comboTree3.getSelectedIds());
});
```

More detail you can found here https://github.com/erhanfirat/combo-tree